# Spring Boot application not working in EKS (Kubernetes)

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

I have a legacy spring boot application that's perfectly running in AWS ECS. When I deployed it in EKS, I'm encountering the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field <>.config.ComponentsHealthEndpoint required a single bean, but 3 were found:
        - livenessStateHealthIndicator: defined by method 'livenessStateHealthIndicator' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/availability/AvailabilityProbesAutoConfiguration.class]
        - readinessStateHealthIndicator: defined by method 'readinessStateHealthIndicator' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/availability/AvailabilityProbesAutoConfiguration.class]
        - diskSpaceHealthIndicator: defined by method 'diskSpaceHealthIndicator' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/system/DiskSpaceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]
```

I have defined the data source url, password and username in configmap the same in ECS.
I also verified that I can connect to database from inside the EKS cluster.

Here is my EKS deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: <MY_SERVICE>-chart
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: staging
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: <MY_SERVICE>
    app.kubernetes.io/version: latest
    environment: staging
    helm.sh/chart: <MY_SERVICE>-0.1.0
  name: <MY_SERVICE>-deployment
  namespace: staging
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: <MY_SERVICE>
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: <MY_SERVICE>
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: datasource.password
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: datasource-password
        - name: datasource.username
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: username
              name: datasource-username
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: <MY_SERVICE>-config
        image: <MY_IMAGE_REGISTRY>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 9595
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          periodSeconds: 60
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 120
        name: <MY_SERVICE>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9595
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 9595
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 1Gi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

I also tried to replicate the error in ECS, error in password/url/connection shows different error logs from the above. To be more exact, when I put wrong db url/password in ECS environment variables, the logs show connection refused/connection timeout/bad request.

Here's my code for ComponentsHealthEndpoint.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.ReadOperation;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import <>.common.constants.ApplicationConstants;
import <>.common.properties.GremlinProperties;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@Component
@Profile("health")
@Endpoint(id = "components-health")
public class ComponentsHealthEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private GremlinProperties gremlinProperties;
    @Value(value = "${<>.queueName}")
    private String sqsQueue;
    @Autowired
    private AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync;
    @Autowired
    private HealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator;
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private static final String STATUS_LABEL = "status";

    @ReadOperation
    public Map<String, Status> health() {
        List<Object> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles());
        int count = 0;
        Map<String, Status> componentsHealthMap = Maps.newHashMap();
        // Neptune
        if (activeProfiles.contains("gremlin")) {
            for (String endpoint : gremlinProperties.getProperties().get(ApplicationConstants.READ_PROPERTIES_KEY).getHealthEndpoint()) {
                count++;
                componentsHealthMap.put("neptuneReadCluster" + count, neptune(endpoint));
            }
            count = 0;
            for (String endpoint : gremlinProperties.getProperties().get(ApplicationConstants.WRITE_PROPERTIES_KEY).getHealthEndpoint()) {
                count++;
                componentsHealthMap.put("neptuneWriteCluster" + count, neptune(endpoint));
            }
        }
        // Queue
        if (activeProfiles.contains("sqs")) {
            componentsHealthMap.put("sqsQueue", queue());
        }
        // Database
        if (activeProfiles.contains("datasource")) {
            componentsHealthMap.put("dataSource", dataSource());
        }

        return componentsHealthMap;
    }

    private Status neptune(String endpoint) {
        try {
            ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                    endpoint, HttpMethod.GET, null,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    });
            if (!"healthy".equals(responseEntity.getBody().get(STATUS_LABEL))) {
                return Status.DOWN;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot connect to Neptune instance", e);
            return Status.DOWN;
        }

        return Status.UP;
    }

    public Status queue() {
        try {
            amazonSQSAsync.getQueueUrl(sqsQueue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot connect to SQS Queue", e);
            return Status.DOWN;
        }
        return Status.UP;
    }

    public Status dataSource() {
        try {
            Health dbHealth = dbHealthIndicator.health();
            if ("H2".equals(dbHealth.getDetails().get("database"))) {
                return Status.DOWN;
            } else {
                return dbHealth.getStatus();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot connect to Database", e);
            return Status.DOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the full log

````
02:22:14.345 [main] DEBUG <>.Application - LOG_HOME parameter does not exist, setting to default : ${HOME}/logs
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.5)
2023-03-17 02:22:15,772  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] <>.Application  : Starting Application v1.12 using Java 1.8.0_345 on <>-deployment-7d8584db88-jj5h7 with PID 7 (/root/app/<>-1.12.jar started by root in /root/app)
2023-03-17 02:22:15,773  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] <>.Application  : The following 6 profiles are active: "<>", "aws", "health", "datasource", "logging", "dev"
2023-03-17 02:22:18,061  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-17 02:22:18,243  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 168 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-17 02:22:22,428  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#65d09a04' of type [com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-03-17 02:22:22,434  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#707194ba' of type [com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-03-17 02:22:22,436  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'credentialsProvider' of type [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.credentials.CredentialsProviderFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-03-17 02:22:22,436  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'credentialsProvider' of type [com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-03-17 02:22:23,363  WARN 7 [           main] [] [] [] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2023-03-17 02:22:23,363  WARN 7 [           main] [] [] [] io.undertow.websockets.jsr               : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2023-03-17 02:22:23,442  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] io.undertow.servlet                      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-17 02:22:23,443  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7490 ms
2023-03-17 02:22:23,869  WARN 7 [           main] [] [] [] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'components-health' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2023-03-17 02:22:23,869  WARN 7 [           main] [] [] [] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'components-health' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2023-03-17 02:22:24,435  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: <>]
2023-03-17 02:22:24,637  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
2023-03-17 02:22:25,262  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-03-17 02:22:26,245  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2023-03-17 02:22:28,150  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-17 02:22:28,167  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit '<>'
2023-03-17 02:22:31,668  WARN 7 [           main] [] [] [] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'componentsHealthEndpoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dbHealthIndicator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: livenessStateHealthIndicator,readinessStateHealthIndicator,diskSpaceHealthIndicator
2023-03-17 02:22:31,668  WARN 7 [           main] [] [] [] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'componentsHealthEndpoint': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dbHealthIndicator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: livenessStateHealthIndicator,readinessStateHealthIndicator,diskSpaceHealthIndicator
2023-03-17 02:22:31,670  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit '<>'
2023-03-17 02:22:31,739  INFO 7 [           main] [] [] [] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-17 02:22:31,778 ERROR 7 [           main] [] [] [] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Field dbHealthIndicator in <>.common.config.ComponentsHealthEndpoint required a single bean, but 3 were found:
        - livenessStateHealthIndicator: defined by method 'livenessStateHealthIndicator' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/availability/AvailabilityProbesAutoConfiguration.class]
        - readinessStateHealthIndicator: defined by method 'readinessStateHealthIndicator' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/availability/AvailabilityProbesAutoConfiguration.class]
        - diskSpaceHealthIndicator: defined by method 'diskSpaceHealthIndicator' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/system/DiskSpaceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]
Action:
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
2023-03-17 02:22:31,778 ERROR 7 [           main] [] [] [] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : ```
The deployment should work same in ECS.

What am I missing here?
````

Comment: The failure's occurring on EKS as Spring Boot auto-configures liveness and readiness probes on Kubernetes. This is causing a problem with `ComponentsHealthEndpoint` which wants a single bean of a particular type but 3 are now available. Can you share the code for `ComponentsHealthEndpoint`? I would guess that its `dbHealthIndicator` is too loosely typed.

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson, I've added the code for ComponentsHealthEndpoint in the description. When I deployed the application, these profiles are active : "aws", "health", "datasource", "logging", "dev"

Comment: @AndyWilkinson So I've defined org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator and got this error:

Field dbHealthIndicator in org.voyager.cpe.geass.codedossier.common.config.ComponentsHealthEndpoint required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator' that could not be found.

Comment: Then your app was incorrectly interpreting another health indicator as being  for a `DataSource`. Looking more closely at the logs, that was probably `DiskSpaceHealthIndicator`. You either need to make the injection of `DataSourceHealthIndicator` optional or change the app elsewhere so that there's always a `DataSourceHealthIndicator` bean.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject a single bean of type `HealthIndicator` into `ComponentsHealthEndpoint`. This is happening due to this autowired field:

```java
@Autowired
private HealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator;
```

This will fail when there isn't exactly one `HealthIndicator` bean in the application context. You can avoid the problem by giving the field a more specific type. Looking at the code, `org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator` would be appropriate here:

```
@Autowired
private DataSourceHealthIndicator dbHealthIndicator;
```